# I didn't do nothing or anything

Tags: colloquial-language, multiple-negation, negative-concord

Usually when I want to deny something I will say **I didn't do anything**

However, lately I watched some movies in which the people sometimes said  **I didn't do nothing**

They use **no** instead of **any**, like **I don't have no problem**. I think this sounds cool.

Can I use it in my daily chatting?

Comment: It is informal and it is used especially in  conversations: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+didn%27t+do+nothing&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20did%20not%20do%20nothing%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What constitutes a double negative?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31671/what-constitutes-a-double-negative)

Answer (score 5):

This is called [negative concord](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/negative-concord) or [multiple negation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negative) and it is used in African-American and Southern American English.

This construction is used widely enough that most people will understand you if you use it, so go ahead and use it if you feel like it.  However, you should avoid it in formal use, as it is not considered grammatical in modern standard English.

Answer (score 1):

It is grammatically wrong and not very sophisticated, but most people will probably understand it. So, I guess, you can use it in your "daily chatting", but should avoid it in formal speech.